Chronomorphisms in Scala
I'm learning recursion patterns, but I can't figure out the usefulness of futumorphism and histomorphism.
The couple of Scala examples I found look very unconvincing. I also found Haskell examples, but I can't figure them out.
Suppose we have functions like this:
def futu  [F[_]: Functor, X]: (X => Free[F, X]  ) => X => Fix[F]
def histo [F[_]: Functor, X]: (Cofree[F, X] => X) => Fix[F] => X

def ana   [F[_]: Functor, X]: (X => F[X]) => X => Fix[F]
def dynamo[F[_]: Functor, A, B]: (A => F[A], Cofree[F, B] => B) => A => B =  
  (coalg, alg) => ana(coalg) andThen histo(alg)

Can anyone give some good Scala examples of using

futu?
dynamo (histo within) applied to a typical dynamic programming problem?

And where exactly is the reference to "past" and "future" values ​​there?

Unless you are writing a compiler - where you unfold String/InputStream into AST and then fold AST into the result of compilation, with several intermediate mappings, it's very hard to find a use case for recursive schemes, and outside of (now dead) SlamData's Quasar I saw no place where they would be useful.

Dynamic programming is popular now, and dynamo is positioned as a suitable tool for such tasks. I want to believe that these are not empty words.))) I found such an example but I don't know Haskell well((
Perhaps there are useful Haskell examples with futu, but this will also require translation to Scala...
And I want to better understand why these morphisms have such names.

Recall futu (right, green is Bind, red is Pure) produces multiple steps at a time, and histo (left, Red is CoFree) consumes multiple steps at a time. Below you're pretty-printing a superscript exponential expression by looking into the history, or inserting a binary Plus tree when parsing an associative expression.

Here are three examples of futu
// given the following function computes the adjacency list of an algebraic graph
def toAdj[V] = cata[[X] =>> Graph[V, X], Map[V, Set[V]]]{
  case Empty => Map()
  case Vertex(a) => Map(a -> Set())
  case Overlay(l, r) => l.mergeWith(r)(_ | _)
  case Connect(l, r) => l.mergeWith(r)(_ | _)
    .mergeWith(l.keySet.map((_, r.keySet)).toMap)(_ | _)
}
// this function creates an algebraic graph from an adjacency matrix
def fromAdj[K, V] = futu[[X] =>> Graph[V, X], Iterable[(V, Set[V])]]{
  case (v, nbs)::tail => Overlay(Free.Pure(tail), Free.Bind(
    Connect(Free.Bind(Vertex(v)),
            nbs.foldLeft(Free.Bind(Empty))((t, k) => Free.Bind(Overlay(t, Free.Bind(Vertex(k))))))))
  case Nil => Empty
}
// A simple algebraic graph constructor 
def path[V] = futu[[X] =>> Graph[V, X], Iterable[V]]{
  case x::y::Nil => Connect(Free.Bind(Vertex(x)), Free.Bind(Vertex(y)))
  case x::y::tail => Overlay(Free.Pure(x::y::Nil), Free.Pure(y::tail))
  case _ => Empty
}
// Converting a Tree instead
def tree[V] = futu[[X] =>> Graph[V, X], Tree[V]]{
  case Fix((v, Nil)) => Vertex(v)
  case Fix((v, xs)) =>
    val leaves = xs.collect[Free[[X] =>> Graph[V, X], Tree[V]]]{case Fix((s, _)) => Free.Bind(Vertex(s))}
    val branches = xs.collect[Free[[X] =>> Graph[V, X], Tree[V]]]{case x @ Fix((_, cs)) if cs.nonEmpty => Free.Pure(x)}
    val level = Connect(Free.Bind(Vertex(v)),
                        leaves.tail.foldLeft(leaves.head)((t, x) => Free.Bind(Overlay(t, x))))
    if branches.isEmpty then level
    else Overlay(Free.Bind(level),
                 branches.tail.foldRight(branches.head)((x, t) => Free.Bind(Overlay(t, x))))
}

And an example of Fibonacci histo in Python you can translate yourself
def fib_alg(fh):
    if isinstance(fh, Z): return 1
    elif isinstance(fh.pred.fa, Z): return 1
    else: return fh.pred.a + fh.pred.fa.pred.a


For reference, the definitions of futu and cata (chrono being their composite)
def futu[F[_] : Functor, A](coalg: A => F[Free[F, A]])(a: A): Fix[F] =
  def picking(ff: Free[F, A]): Fix[F] = ff match
    case Free.Pure(a) => futu(coalg)(a)
    case Free.Bind(ff) => Fix(ff.map(picking))
  Fix(coalg(a).map(picking))

def histo[F[_] : Functor, A](alg: F[CoFree[F, A]] => A)(fix: Fix[F]): A =
  def bundling(fix: Fix[F]): CoFree[F, A] =
    CoFree(histo(alg)(fix), fix.unFix.map(bundling))
  alg(fix.unFix.map(bundling))

All code here was taken from https://github.com/Adam-Vandervorst/RecursionSchemes

Thank a lot, @Adam! It need some time to understand your sources (why Overlay, etc), but it looks hopefull)) Could you please point the place, where “future values” are used? Why is it called “futumorphism”?

@SergeySviridov https://github.com/algebraic-graphs/scala/blob/master/src/main/scala/alga/Graph.scala may be instructive for understanding e.g. Overlay. The best resource on the topic is likely https://jtobin.io/time-traveling-recursion (and their other blog posts). It's not "values from the future" but "values that would've been generated in the future, generated now". You see, in the futu implementation, it skips over all Bind's you already inserted and continues calling your coalg only when it encounters Pure.

To summarize Adam's answer.
The Fibonacci sequence is not the best example for demonstrating histomorphism (para or even cata would be better), but it does demonstrate references to previously calculated values. The Fibonacci sequence can also be considered an example of a dynamic programming problem (though I hope to find a more typical example).
Using futumorphism with graphs is a good way to demonstrate references to "future values". In Adam's example, the coalgebra in fromAdj contains code like Overlay(Free.Pure(tail), Free.Bind(...)). There are two graphs overlaying - the one that is calculated right now in Free.Bind, and the other one that has not yet been calculated (tail), but will be calculated in the future.
